# Не работает страница 404

Tags: wordpress

Сайт на WP 5.5.3 (+WooCommerce), постоянные ссылки - postname, дефолтный шаблон 404.php, [htaccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB7jY.jpg) также дефолтный, главная front-page.php

*Суть проблемы*: не отрабатывает страница 404, при попытке открыть несуществующую страницу, идет перенаправление на главную страницу. Например, https://site.com/test404page -> https://site.com

Что пробовал:

- выключить все плагины, переключиться на дефолтный шаблон (twentytwenty);
- выкачал и развернул бекап на локалке (OpenServer): 404 работает как надо (почему так - непонятно)
- писал хостеру. Ответил, что проблема не на стороне хостинга. (Сервер вроде как на nginx)

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема, куда копать?

Comment: Если у них nginx, то htaccess не нужен. Возможно, у них кривой конфиг nginx.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, спасибо. Написал хостеру повторно с просьбой проверить конфиги. Обещали еще раз посмотреть. По результату отпишусь.

Comment: Здесь настройки nginx для WP: https://wordpress.org/support/article/nginx/

Comment: Прежде всего проверяй ответ сервера  сторонними сервисами, а не локально.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, вы были правы. Проблема была на стороне хостера. Сегодня уже ответил другой спец из поддержки: "Я внес изменения на стороне веб-сервера. Самостоятельно изменить вы не сможете."